# Trying to get records from database and pass to controller

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to send notifications after second user makes a bid in game, to a user who made first bid in a game.

I have table game_bids where I have id, user_id and game_id. 
I tried to find game_id from table which equals to currently opened game.

I am not good at laravel and can't figure it out how to make it work correctly. I need help with $user = (which I will pass to notify).

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\User;
use App\Game_bid;
use App\Game;
use Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang;
use DB;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Notification;
use App\Notifications\GameBiddedNotification;


class PointsController extends Controller {
public function bid($game_id) {
        $bid = new Game_bid;
        $bid->game_id = $game_id;
        $bid->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
        $bid->is_awarded = 0;

        if ($bid->save()) {
            $game = Game::find($game_id);
            $user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);
            $user->points = $user->points - $game->points;
            $user->save();
        }

        **$user = Game_bid::where('user_id')
                ->where('game_id', Game::find($game_id))
                ->first();**

        $details = [
                'greeting' => $game->title,
                'body' => '.',
                'thanks' => '!',
        ];

        $user->notify(new \App\Notifications\GameBiddedNotification($details));

        return redirect('my_bids')->with('success', 'Your bid placed successfully');
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly there can be more than one users to notify (everyone who had made a bid on this game). So to retrieve and notify all other users that have bidded on this game you can do something like this:

```
public function bid($game_id) {
    $bid = new Game_bid;
    $bid->game_id = $game_id;
    $bid->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $bid->is_awarded = 0;

    if ($bid->save()) {
        $game = Game::find($game_id);
        $user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);
        $user->points = $user->points - $game->points;
        $user->save();
    }

    $users = User::whereHas('game_bids', function ($query) use ($game_id, $bid) {
        $query->where('game_id', $game_id)->where('user_id', '!=', $bid->user_id);
    })->get();

    $details = [
        'greeting' => $game->title,
        'body' => '.',
        'thanks' => '!',
    ];

    foreach ($users as $user) {
        $user->notify(new \App\Notifications\GameBiddedNotification($details));
    }

    return redirect('my_bids')->with('success', 'Your bid placed successfully');
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. yes there can be more then one users who will bid, most important is that first user who will bid should receive notification once one more user places a bid. I am receiving this error: BadMethodCallException
Call to undefined method App\User::game_bids()

Comment: You must change 'game_bids' to whatever you defined your relation to game_bids as, check your user model it should look something like this: `public function game_bids() { return $this->hasMany('App\Game_bid') }` then replace 'game_bids with that function name.

Comment: Sorry, I think you copy pasted the code, I accidently missed  a `>` character when chaning the second `where()` condition on the `$query`, I updated the answer.

Comment: Glad to help! 